# Doubly linked list reversing - printing out garbage data

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I've got problem with this part of code. My goal is to reverse a doubly linked list. I receive garbage values when I try to print out reversed list.

```
typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct list{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;

void pushFront(List* l, Node* node){
    if(l->head == NULL){
        l->head = node;
        l->tail = node;
        l->tail->next = NULL;
    }else{
        l->head->prev = node;
        node->next = l->head;
        l->head = node;
    }
}
void printList(List* list){

    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%i ",ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    puts("");
    free(ptr);
}

void reverse(List* lista){

    Node* ptr = lista->head;
    Node* temp = NULL;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        temp = ptr->prev;
        ptr->prev = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = temp;
        ptr = ptr->prev;
    }

    if(temp != NULL)
        lista->head = temp->prev;
    free(ptr);
    free(temp);
}
```

Output I receive:

> Original list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>
> Reversed list: 1 8532616 3 4 5 6 7 8528368 2002618240

Comment: `if(temp != NULL) lista->head = temp->prev;` huh? What does this do? The list has a head pointer *and a tail poiner*, what should happen to them?

Comment: In your `printList`, you call `free(ptr)` when done which is tantamount to `free(NULL)` which doesn't do anything but it is not needed for any purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use your function `printList` two times on the same list (once before and once after reversing the list) which leads to undefined behavior as you free your list during `printList` and then try to access and work with those same memory locations -> do not free your stuff when you are not done with it:

```
void printList(List* list){

    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%i ",ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    puts("");
    // free(ptr); --> Remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you freeing the nodes in printList() and reverse()?
In C, you should only free variables, which were previously allocated, with malloc() for example.
When you declare variables in a C function, it will be automatically allocated to the stack or other memory region (or even in the CPU registers). They will also be automatically freed at the end of your function.
If you are dynamically allocating your nodes and then freeing them in your "reverse" function, I would expect to see garbage when you read the freed node.
I tried to remove the "free" calls and the code worked fine.
https://ideone.com/CN1MaC

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct list{
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;

void pushFront(List* l, Node* node){
    if(l->head == NULL){
        l->head = node;
        l->tail = node;
        l->tail->next = NULL;
    }else{
        l->head->prev = node;
        node->next = l->head;
        l->head = node;
    }
}
void printList(List* list){

    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("%i ",ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    puts("");
}

void reverse(List* lista){

    Node* ptr = lista->head;
    Node* temp = NULL;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        temp = ptr->prev;
        ptr->prev = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = temp;
        ptr = ptr->prev;
    }

    if(temp != NULL)
        lista->head = temp->prev;
}

int main(void) {
    List list = { NULL, NULL };
    Node nodeArr[7];
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        nodeArr[i].val = 7 - i;
        nodeArr[i].prev = NULL;
        nodeArr[i].next = NULL;
        pushFront(&list, &nodeArr[i]);
    }

    printList(&list);
    reverse(&list);
    printList(&list);

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```